# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 null / WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to test a POST api using RestTemplate as the client but I am continuously getting an exception. 
I have tried a lot of different solutions but I continue to get this exception.
The details are as below:

By using the following client code:

```
@RequestMapping("/leaders")
    public String showLeaders(HttpSession session, Model theModel) throws Exception {

        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/demo-find-my-hotel/api/get-access-token";


         System.out.println(uri);
        UserDetailsPojo newEmployee = new UserDetailsPojo(
                session.getAttribute("api_key").toString(),
                session.getAttribute("client_secret").toString());

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        UserDetailsPojo result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, newEmployee, 
        UserDetailsPojo.class);

        System.out.println(result);

        return "test";
    }
```

and POJO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserDetailsPojo {
    private String client_id;
    private String client_secret;

    public UserDetailsPojo() {}

    public UserDetailsPojo(String client_id, String client_secret) {
        super();
        this.client_id = client_id;
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
    }
    public String getClient_id() {
        return client_id;
    }
    public void setClient_id(String client_id) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
    }
    public String getClient_secret() {
        return client_secret;
    }
    public void setClient_secret(String client_secret) {
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
    }


}
```

I am trying to call this api:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get-access-token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getAccessToken(@ModelAttribute UserDetailsPojo userDetails) throws Exception {


        System.out.println(userDetails.getClient_id());

        return "yooooooo";
}
```

But I always get this exception:

```
Oct 30, 2019 3:23:36 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
Oct 30, 2019 3:23:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/demo-find-my-hotel] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 null] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 405 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:772)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:432)
    at com.findmyhotel.controller.DemoController.showLeaders(DemoController.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

**ModelAttribute**

Annotation that binds a method parameter or method return value to a named model attribute, exposed to a web view. Supported for controller classes with @RequestMapping methods.
Can be used to expose command objects to a web view, using specific attribute names, through annotating corresponding parameters of an @RequestMapping method.

**RequestBody**

Annotation indicating a method parameter should be bound to the body of the web request. The body of the request is passed through an HttpMessageConverter to resolve the method argument depending on the content type of the request. Optionally, automatic validation can be applied by annotating the argument with @Valid.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-access-token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAccessToken(@RequestBody UserDetailsPojo userDetails) throws Exception {


    System.out.println(userDetails.getClient_id());

    return "yooooooo";
}
```

1. Your API(getAccessToken) method use `@RequestBody`.
2. Check values in `newEmployee`.
3. Request content type default setting application/json in `postForObject`.
4. Search `multiValueMap` or `defaultMessageConverter`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `@ModelAttribute` as controller param, then you need to send your data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` something like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> variables = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
variables.add("client_id", session.getAttribute("api_key").toString());
variables.add("client_secret", session.getAttribute("client_secret").toString());

HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(variables, 
requestHeaders);

String uri = "http://localhost:8080/demo-find-my-hotel/api/get-access-token";

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, 
requestEntity, UserDetailsPojo.class);
```